# Registering onclick handler for *all* KML features in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

I am new to using OpenLayers with JQuery to display vector data from KML files. I'm creating the layer like this:

```js
newlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( layerid, {
    projection: MAPVAR.displayProjection,
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: layerurl,
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
            extractStyles: true, 
            extractAttributes: true,
            maxDepth: 2
        })
      }) 
    });
```

I want to avoid using these vector features with the OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature control. Instead i would like to have each svg feature respond to a click event and pop open their own individual windows with the attributes.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add the onclick function to **ALL** the vector features loaded.

For example, I can attach a function to the KML layer's "loadend" event and add the onclick function doing the following:

```js
$('g[id$=vroot] > *').css("cursor", "pointer")
$('g[id$=vroot] > *').click(function(evt){ $w = $.WM_open(); $w.find('.windowcontent').append("SUCKER"); });
```

But this will only apply the handler to those vector elements in the view extent and not the ones that are waiting to be rendered in the HTML. I'm not sure how to access the unrendered ones -- they are in the DOM.

I've come up with a poor workaround to this problem, but I know there has to be a better way.

Is there some way I can dynamically create the "onclick" handler for each svg feature when they are getting parsed?

Would that require me to subclass OpenLayers.Layers.Vector or OpenLayers.Formats.KML?

Does anyone have an example or recommendation on other ways?

---

I still have not solved adding the onclick handler to the features. But i was able to override OpenLayers.Format.KML parseData() to add a pointer cursor to the feature styles before the loadend runs on the KML layer (additions demarcated with *** EDITS ***).

```js
var FormatErmaKml = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Format.KML, { 
parseData: function (data, b) { 
    typeof data == "string" && (data = OpenLayers.Format.XML.prototype.read.apply(this, [data]));
    for (var c = ["Link", "NetworkLink", "Style", "StyleMap", "Placemark"], d = 0, e = c.length; d < e; ++d) {
        var f = c[d];
        var g = this.getElementsByTagNameNS(data, "*", f);  
        if (g.length != 0) switch (f.toLowerCase()) {
        case "link":
        case "networklink":
            this.parseLinks(g, b);  
            break;
        case "style":
            this.extractStyles && this.parseStyles(g, b);  
            break;
        case "stylemap":
            this.extractStyles && this.parseStyleMaps(g, b);  
            break;
        case "placemark":
            this.parseFeatures(g, b)
        }    
  
    }    
    **** EDITS BEGIN ****
    for(var count = 0; count < this.features.length; ++count){
            f = this.features[count];
            f.style.cursor = "pointer";
    }
    **** END EDITS ****
    return this.features
},});
```

Comment: I still have not solved adding the onclick handler to the features. But i was able to override OpenLayers.Format.KML parseData() to add a pointer cursor to the feature styles.

Comment: for a pointer cursor: When you define your layer you can define a stylemap and put `cursor: "pointer"`.

Comment: I have tried to do what you are asking with no result. Maybe if you try an SVG framework like rafael or jQuery SVG. The problem i have with SelectFeature is that you can't just bind a click to a feature.. it automatically triggers select, redraw, etc. I'm assuming that is why you don't want to use SelectFeature. So if you do figure it out, please post the answer.

Comment: @capdragon -- yes, that's another reason why i would like to not use SelectFeature control

Comment: @maztaz just something to consider, if you haven't before, but IE 8 and lower is VML only, so Canvas-specific functionality won't work.  But...of course depends on what browsers you're targeting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe i found the solution.

**[SOLUTION DEMONSTRATION](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/ol/clickhandler.htm)**

It will:

1. change the cursor for your feature to `cursor:wait` using jquery.
2. It will change the svg fill color of the feature using jquery.
3. And best of all it's efficient and will NOT trigger anything or disrupt anything
   else as far as my tests have shown.

Use a regular [click Handler](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Click-js.html) ([EXAMPLE1](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/click.html), [EXAMPLE2](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/click-handler.html)) and use the `e.target` to get the object on the map. If it returns a vector feature great, if not, ignore. It can work for all your layers or you can check the returned feature to see if it belongs to a layer you want it to trigger on.

I used [Example #1](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/click.html) and replaced the latlon alert for this:

```
    if (e.target._featureId) {
        var feature = vectorLayer.getFeatureById(e.target._featureId);
        $(e.target).css('fill', '#000000');
        $(e.target).css('cursor', 'wait');
        $("div#info").append("<span>You just clicked on " + feature.id + "<span><br />");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your original question but show you how to define a cursor on all the features on a layer:

```js
newlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(layerid, {
    projection: MAPVAR.displayProjection,
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
            strokeColor: '#000000',
            strokeOpacity: .3,
            strokeWidth: 2,
            fillColor: '#000000',
            fillOpacity: 0,
            cursor: "pointer"
        })
    }),
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: layerurl,
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
            extractStyles: true,
            extractAttributes: true,
            maxDepth: 2
        })
    })
});
```

---

Here's an **[EXAMPLE](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/ol/feature_cursor.htm)**

Comment: that didn't seem to work...debugging it now but "default" is overwritten with new style after loadend...hmmm

Comment: Sure it does... check my simple example i uploaded. It has the "waiting" cursor on the features. Make sure you are not overwriting the style on loadend.

Comment: thx....i'll have to debug mine more to figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

-- edited 1/19 9:45am per @capdragon's comment

Why add on-click to each feature?  That is far too expensive.  Why not add it to the layer?

Then the 2nd question is, how to add same handler to multiple layers.

1. Create one click handler
2. Keep an in-memory array of layers that you pass to this handler
3. Update click handler whenever a new layer is added or removed
4. Create all your handler functions, and inside the on-click you can find out easily what feature was clicked on

1)

```js
var hoverAndClickControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
                mylayers // this is the array of layers you're keeping in memory
                ,{
                    callbacks:
                    {
                          click: onFeatureSelect
                        , clickout: onFeatureUnselect
                        , over:  onFeatureHover
                        , out: onFeatureUnhover
                    }
                }
            );
```

3)

```js
function addLayerToHandler(p_layer)
{
   // add layer to array
   // e.g. mylayers.push(p_layer);

   // update click handler
   // handler.setLayers(mylayers);  // since OL 2.9

}
```

4)

```js
function onFeatureSelect(p_feature)
{
  // hey, feature you want is the parameter.  do whatever you need to do 

  // create a pop-up balloon, or send data to server, alert user, write out data, etc
}
```

Comment: OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature DOES support multiple layers out of the box. You just add layers with `myselfeatureControl.setLayers([layer1,layer2]);` (+1) for trying to convince to use 1 handler instead of one for each feature.

Comment: @capdragon  I stand corrected on the lack of setLayers() function.  Just checked the trunk source, looks very similar to all the other rigamarole I was doing to deactivate handler, remove layers, re-add the layers and re-activate.  One of my products is still on 2.8 and there's no such function in 2.8.  Looks like it was introduce in 2.9.1.

Comment: @Vadim -- all that advice looks great...but I really want to avoid using OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature control as I said in the original post even if other options are expensive. Is there another way?

Comment: @Vadim Ahh, yes you're right.

Comment: @maztaz I'm not sure why you don't want 1 handler?  In the handler you can easily create an individual pop-up for each feature.  It's not like one popup kills the other.  You can certainly manage state (when one opens, kill all others) or you can let user manage it by clicking the "x" in popup.  What we also do is keep track, if feature has popup and user clicks on feature again, we kill the popup.  So it's a toggle on/off.  You can do a lot in just the single handler and you're going to have a memory problem by attaching to each feature.

Comment: @Vadim -- i've played around with your solution before in OL 2.11 using setLayers() function on the select control. But if you have a lot of other controls in the mix it seems like the event handling for a feature can be convoluted -- more than one event gets mixed up, at least that's what I remember when I was using it. I might give it another shot

Comment: I feel maztza pain, the problem i have with OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature is that it does not do a simple "click". it does select, redraw, etc. EVERY time. So maybe i have a feature that is already selected but i want to do some different processing if it's clicked without re-selecting my feature which is registered to a whole chain of events. I can't do a simple "Click" without the baggage.

Comment: i reworked everything with select control and i remember a few more reasons why i didn't like this solution. 1) I want select control on by default for all KML layers i load. I don't want to have a control switcher for just for vectors -- that seems silly. But managing all controls on toolbar while SelectControl is in the background always activated becomes a pain. 2) SelectControl does what capdragon mentioned above in terms of EVERY event firing. 3) maybe it's me but I constantly have problems with click, selectfeature event firing...sometimes it doesn't