# OpenLayers ZoomBox control kills SelectFeature event firing

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a navigation toolbar with some common OL controls such as Navigation and ZoomBox on it.

I also have a SelectFeature control that isn't part of the navigation toolbar b/c it should be active all the time for vector features. Each layer that is added to the SelectFeature control using setLayers() has a handler registered to the 'featureselected' event.

However, in cases where I choose the ZoomBox control my ability to select vector features disappears. I have to refresh the layer to get it back. I can work with the Navigation control (in fact many other controls too) and still have my vectors responding to the select event.

Has anyone else experienced this or know a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You could add button for SelectFeature control into panel and deactivate ZoomBox control when SelectFeature control is active. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/_DR_/XJCjk/) is my little example.

Comment: I agree. You're either selecting, panning, or zoomboxing but you cannot have them all active at once. I'm sure that's why OpenLayers deactivates the selectControl when you're panning.

Comment: thanks for the response guys. this was the main reason then that I wanted to create separate onclick handlers for each svg vector feature even if it's expensive. thx for the help

Comment: @maztaz i found a solution to that http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/how-to-register-onclick-handler-for-all-kml-feaures-in-openlayers/19088#19088